# Chain of Stan is failed due to lookup error: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

Tags: r, gcc, stan

By running in R (I use emacs-ess, also tried in terminal)
System Debian GNU/Linux with package manager Guix. R, rstan, rstanheaders installed from Guix.

```
library(rethinking)


f <- alist(
    y ~ dnorm( mu , sigma ),
    mu ~ dnorm( 0 , 10 ),
    sigma ~ dexp( 1 )
)
fit_stan <- ulam( f , data=list(y=c(-1,1)) )
```

gives the output

> Compiling Stan program...
> Running MCMC with 1 chain, with 1 thread(s) per chain...

> Chain 1 ./ulam_cmdstanr_8b4a70079e6636864e593d38ad729313_threads: symbol lookup error: /gnu/store/5h2w4qi9hk1qzzgi1w83220ydslinr4s-glibc-2.33/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
> Warning: Chain 1 finished unexpectedly!

> Error in rstan::read_stan_csv(cmdstanfit$output_files()) :
> csvfiles does not contain any CSV file name
> Additional: warning:
> No chains finished successfully. Unable to retrieve the fit.

And this is Makevars

CXX14FLAGS=-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC

CXX14=/home/.../.guix-profile/bin/g++

I tried to run the code of the model in R and Stan and expected that to succesfully compile the chain.